# Website displays image that is not associated with img src

Tags: image, nginx, uiwebview

I have an iOS app that contains a UIWebView, which display a webpage. Sometimes the page displays a different image than the one associated with the src link.

A user sent me a screenshot where it was clear that one of the icon images had been replaced with a completely different image. The same wrong image was displayed in each of the instances where this icon was supposed to be displayed. Refreshing did not solve the issue, but closing and opening the app did. (Or maybe she actually deleted and reinstalled the app.)

The html for the icon is just an img:

```
<img src = "/the_icon_source">
```

The img src is hardcoded directly into the HTML file. I therefore don't see that the HTML itself could have been wrong or said anything besides "/the_icon_source".

So how can the wrong image be associated with an image src? Could the server be sending the wrong image when it's asked for "/the_icon_source"? Could the iOS app be caching incorrectly, mixing up images? How to test and fix?

I myself cannot reproduce this issue. I'm not sure how often it occurs, but several users have mentioned it, also for other images on the page. They have only mentioned it occurring in the app, not on the website. This may just be because the app is used more than the website.

My host is Webfaction and the images are served using [WebFaction server’s static-only front-end nginx process](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/static.html). The app displays the website in a UIWebView. (Webfaction suppprt merely told me that they served the right images.)

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem not that you have it like this:

> img src = "/the_icon_source"

rather than like this:

> img src = ".the_icon_source"

If this is sat on a linux server the / will be pointing to the root directory whereas the . or simply the_icon_source would simply point to the directory in which the website is sat which i assume is where the image is also located.